# Illustrator SVG export not working (namespace prefix inkscape not defined)

Tags: html, graphics, vector, svg, inkscape

I'm new to the world of vector editing. I'm trying to export a .SVG file from a .AI file.
However, when I export it, I get the following error in the generated file:

```
Error on line 57 at column 354: Namespace prefix inkscape for cy on namedview is not defined
```

Could someone please tell me what this means and how I can fix it?

Answer (score 8):

Try to open your SVG file with a text editor: you'll see some XML attributes with the inkscape namespace, like for instance

```
inkscape:label="Some label"
```

These attributes are probably coming from the original SVG file (I'm guessing you grab it from Wikipedia?). You can safely remove them all -- maybe with a grep find and replace in your text editor like :

```
find inkscape:label="[^"]*" replace with ""
```

Comment: Is that find command pseudo code? I've never seen syntax like that.

Comment: @DannyArmstrong, "grep find and replace" isn't a typo. It'll make your life better though.

Answer (score 6):

I sure hope they'll eventually fix this. To Adobe's credit, the cause of this problem is that Illustrator is trying to preserve information that it doesn't use, to play nice with other programs.

There are several workarounds.

1. Use InkScape to Save As Plain SVG. This works well if you know about the problem up front and can simply save off a plain copy from InkScape before ever importing into AI. Or, if you did NOT know up front but don't mind starting over and retweaking any "bad" elements that you've changed since importing from InkScape, you can save as plain from InkScape and then pull in and re-tweak just those problematic elements. However, if you want to do post-processing rather than fixing the AI file (see Chip's answer), the quickest and least-destructive option is probably to use a regular expression (regex, see below) rather than using InkScape.
2. Export to SVG. The newest release of Illustrator now lets you Export to SVG as an alternative to doing a Save a Copy / Save As. Even when there are elements that originally came from InkScape, this produces a file that both Chrome and InkScape are able to open, whereas neither one could open the invalid one I'd created using Save A Copy. WARNING: At my very small scales (16-pixel-high icons), this "web-optimized" export visibly lost information/precision--even at 5 decimals of precision--though it did get rid of the critical error.
3. [ UPDATE: **Save a Copy** / Save As SVG is feasible now. I just upgraded both programs and it seems that InkScape is now able to open the invalid files created by Illustrator, though Chrome and Illustrator still cannot. I expect this means that doing a Save As from Illustrator and then a Save As Plain from InkScape is the now the **quickest** way to get a clean SVG that is also precise (though InkScape does warn that Plain can lose some kinds of data). ]
4. **Fix the SVG code**. Philippe's solution seems like the **best** way to truly fix what's currently broken in the latest file without losing (much?) precision/information. In Notepad++ it worked for me to replace this regex with nothing: `inkscape:[^"]+"[^"]+"` or, more safely, `inkscape:(export-|connector-curvature)[^"]+"[^"]+"` . Once you've saved a copy as SVG and manually identified and fixed the problems, Illustrator is able to open the SVG file, so you can then copy/paste just the offending elements back into the AI file and put the problem to rest. Whew.

Note: a manual way to identify the "bad" elements without looking at any SVG code is to break things down into artboards, save as SVG, and see which ones cannot be opened. Once you know this, you could use one of the workarounds above to replace just those pieces (since you'd still be losing precision on those ones).

Answer (score 2):

Inkscape allows you to save files as plain. That will get rid of the Inkscape references. There is also a command line (bash) method for batch work.

```
for i in *.svg; do inkscape -z -f $i -l $i; done
```

This can be done to the "Saved As" SVG files created from Illustrator (Illustrator does not export SVG at this point). I have not yet figured out how to get the references out of the Illustrator files once they are in there. Right now, I am stuck with post-processing all Illustrator-created SVG files.

Comment: Saving as plain from InkScape worked for me--thanks! I'll post an alternative approach that also seems to work.

Comment: Illustrator is doing a lot better at dealing with SVGs. Still see weird stuff sometimes.

Comment: As @Chip mentioned, recent versions of Illustrator seem to be producing valid/standard SVGs.